# Fancybox display error

Tags: fancybox

Ey people
i recently designed a popup html file that's being called through fancybox inside my magento-template.

It works fine for all the pages except [the homepage](http://www.tapet-online.ro) where it appears dislocated at the end of the page instead of appearing in the center of the window.

Firebug isnt having any errors for me and i,being a newbie, dont know where to look.

Some pointings,anyone?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading 3 instances of Fancybox :

http://www.tapet-online.ro/skin/frontend/default/acumen/js/jquery.fancybox-1.2.5.pack.js

http://www.tapet-online.ro/skin/frontend/default/acumen/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js

http://www.tapet-online.ro/skin/frontend/default/acumen/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js

you only need a single one, may be this:

http://www.tapet-online.ro/skin/frontend/default/acumen/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the thing.